# Absolute position issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to setup a element B's absolute position on top of element A. I have

```
var left = $('#elementA').offset().left;

var top  = $('#elementA').offset().top;


---------------------------
|    -----------           |    
|   |o          |          |        
|   |           |          |
|   |           |          |
|   |           |          |    
|    -----------           |
|--------------------------
```

o means my elementA.

I want to put element B the same location as element A

```
$('elementB').css({ position:'absolute',
            top:top,
            left:left}) 


---------------------------
|    -----------          | 
|   |o          |         |     
|   |  b        |         |
|   |           |         |
|   |           |         | 
|    -----------          |
|--------------------------
b means my element b
```

but it turns out like above.

If I set

```
$('elementB').css({ position:'absolute',
            top:0,
            left:0})
```

it would works. but I have many different element B and element A and I can't use 0 for all of them.

Anyone can help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please include the HTML content you're using. Are elements A and B wrapped in another element? If so, absolute positioning is in relation to the element wrapping it.

Comment: Can we see some code? works perfectly fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/uqYSu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI Position plugin to position any element relative to any other element. See: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position

In your case it would be:

```
$('#elementB').position({
  my: 'left top',
  at: 'left top',
  of: '#elementA'
});
```

Also i think it's a good practice to add 'px' to the value of css property, e.g.:

```
$('...').css({
    left: 100 + 'px'
});
```

You should always take into account elements disposition relative to each other as stated above. If parent element is "positioned" then child elements will be positioned not relative to the window, but relative to their parent. If you want more flexibility you can take element B out of the element A (make them siblings).

Answer (score 0):

Function offset() will give you the offset of the element in the window.
What you need is the relative offset of elementA inside its container.

Try position() instead of offset()

Based of the other example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dcFXj/

Answer (score 0):

When an element is a child of another element, absolute positioning isn't really absolute to the window, it's absolute *relative to its parent*. If you want a div's top-left corner to be perfectly in place with it's parent's top left corner, then you want it's `top` and `left` to be exactly zero pixels away from it's parent.  It is only absolute because it ignores all other items that may move it out of place.

[Here's a demonstration of that in action](http://jsfiddle.net/mRsgv/)

When B is a child of A, for every situation where B needs to be aligned with A, just always set it's left and top to 0.